# What is the maximum value of the exponent of single precision floating point on MSVC?

Tags: visual-c++, types, floating-point, double, precision

I've been trying to figure out how biased exponents work.
8 bits are reserved for the exponent itsef, so it's either -127 to 127 or 0 to 255. When i want to store a number(exponent part) that doesn't fit into 8 bits, where it obtains additional bits to store that data from?
In case you are going to say it uses bias as an offset, then provide an additional info on where exactly the data is stored.

Comment: If you are trying to store a number in a `float` variable that is greater than `FLT_MAX` (`2^128`, approximately `3.402823e+38`), an overflow occurs and the value of the variable becomes positive infinity.

Comment: Why do you think a number whose exponent does not fit in eight bits can be stored in a single-precision floating-point object? The maximum exponent code used for finite numbers is 254. With the 127 bias removed, this code represents an exponent of 2^127. Finite numbers whose value is 2^128 and greater cannot be represented in the single-precision format. No additional bits are obtained to store the data because the data is not stored.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, I am still confused. 32 bits for single precision. 1 bit for sign, 8 for exponent and the rest for mantissa. The max number for expo as you said is 254. How is it possible when I store the number 30020.3f? And everything seems to work fine in msvc. How 30k fits into 8 bits? 30020 is for exponent and .3 for fraction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "-14"? The multiplication is by 2^14.

Comment: First, 30020.3 is converted to the nearest value that it representable in the format, 1.8322937488555908203125•2^14, which equals 30020.30078125. 1.8322937488555908203125 is the significand. In binary, it is 1.11010101000100010011100. The 23 bits after the radix point, 11010101000100010011100, are stored in the significand field of the encoding. The exponent, 14 is encoded by adding 127, producing 141, and that is stored in the eight bits of the exponent field.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Thanks, fixed. 2^−14 was in my *ad hoc* code to get numbers to copy and paste, and I copied it too hastily.

Answer (score 0):

To a first approximation, the value of a float with exponent `e` and significand `f` is `1.f x 2^e`. There are special cases to consider regarding subnormals, infinities, NaN etc; but you can ignore those for starters. Essentially, the exponent is really the exponent of the base-2 in IEEE754 notation. So, the comment you made regarding how `30020.3f` fits in 8-bits is simple: Easily. You only need an exponent of `14` to represent that, which is nicely representable in the biased exponent with 8-bits; capable of covering it nicely.

In fact, here's the exact binary binary representation of `30020.3` as a single-precision IEEE-754 float:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 10001101 11010101000100010011010
             Hex: 46EA 889A
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 14 (Stored: 141, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1.d51134p14
           Value: +30020.3 (NORMAL)
```

As you can see we just store `14` in the exponent. The sign is `0`, and the fraction covers the rest so that `1.f * 2^14` gives you the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the maximum value of the exponent of single precision floating point on MSVC?

Maximum value of the binary exponent: 254-BIAS --> **127**

For a decimal perspective, `<float.h>` `FLT_MAX_10_EXP` as the "maximum integer such that 10 raised to that power is in the range of representable finite floating-point numbers,"  **38**

```
printf("%d %g\n", FLT_MAX_10_EXP, FLT_MAX);
// common result
38 3.40282e+38
```

---

> 8 bits are reserved for the exponent itself, so it's either -127 to 127 or 0 to 255.

Pretty close: for finite values, the raw exponent is more like [0...254] with the value of 0 having special meaning: as if *raw exponent* of 1 and `0.` implied digit.

The *exponent* is then *raw exponent* - bias of 127 or [-126 to 127].

Recall this is an exponent for 2 raised to some power.

---

Using [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), the maximum value of a *biased* exponent for finite values is 254.

Applying the bias of `-127`, the maximum value of the exponent is 254-127 or **127** in the form of:

biased_exponent > 0
-1<sup>neg_sign</sup> * 1.(23 bit significant fraction) * 2<sup>biased_exponent - 127</sup>

---

And for completes of subnormals and zero:

biased_exponent == 0
-1<sup>neg_sign</sup> * 0.(23 bit significant fraction) * 2<sup>1 - 127</sup>

---

[How 30k fits into 8 bits? 30020 is for exponent and .3 for fraction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015344/what-is-the-maximum-value-of-the-exponent-of-single-precision-floating-point-on#comment111437825_63015344)

Mathematically 30020.3f has a 30020 whole number portion and a fraction.  30030 is not for the *exponent* and .3 for the fraction used elsewhere.  All the value contribute to the exponent and the *significand*.  `float`s are typically encoded as a binary 1.xxxxx<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>exponent</sup>

```
printf("%a\n", 30020.3f); // 0x1.d51134p+14
```

+1.11010101000100010011010<sub>2</sub> * 2<sup>14</sup>

**Encoding with [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)**

sign + or 0,
biased exponent (14 + 127 = 141 or 10001011<sub>2</sub>)
fraction of significand 11010101000100010011010

0 10001011 11010101000100010011010<sub>2</sub>
01000101 11101010 10001000 10011010<sub>2</sub>
45 EA 88 9A<sub>16</sub>

Comment: i was thinking the whole number has to fit into 8 bits of expo and fraction part into mantissa bits. Hard to follow the explanation tbh. Can you one more time simplify that to the english terms? Significad is ...? As i got it right, it doesn't matter what number i have before fraction, it's going to be encoded into the 23 bits(in case of 33 bits float)?

Comment: @Richard 30020.3 is like 3.00203 * 10^4.  In base 10, 3.00203 is the _significand_,  and 4 is the _exponent_.  In base 2, 1.11010101000100010011010 is the _significand_,  and 0b1110 or 14(decimal) is the _exponent_.  When encoded as a `float`, the fraction of the significand is store along with a biased exponent.